# Is there a way to filter and return results for the unique of one column, with conditions of another?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

**Question**

For the data below, is there a way to return results —for each order in col B— either:

1. If the most recent status [col D] for an order (ex. for order 10021) is closed, then return that row.
2. If not, return every row since the most recent closed status for that order (ex. for order 10020, rows 4 and 5).

[image: data]

**Previous efforts and attempted solutions**

Previously, I was only returning one result, the most recent status for each order with the following:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:D,1,FALSE),9^9,2,2,FALSE)
```

However, I would like if orders can have more than one current status.

I've tried a few things, and was able to achieve what I'm looking for, unfortunately only if there is one order, with the following:

(The linked sheet below explains how I got to this)

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(A2:D5,A2:A5>INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:D5,D2:D5="CLOSED"),1,0),1,1)),FILTER(A2:D5,A2:A5>=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:D5,D2:D5="CLOSED"),1,0),1,1)))
```

The other alternative I can think of is a script with a loop.

**Summary**

It was difficult to know how to title this question but came to it since essentially we're trying to filter for the unique of col B, with conditions against col A & D.

[Here's a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxq3QcRBX6QpSyEe2IGgxq6CTk1zk3Of-YbO09U7N2A/edit?usp=sharing) to a sample Google spreadsheet you can edit, showing all the attempts.

All your help and comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: pls add an example of desired output

Comment: @player0 Sure, added to the bottom of the sheet. Let me know if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

All credit to Matt King who found a complete answer.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:D,(COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,A:A,">="&A:A)=1)*(D:D="CLOSED")
 +NOT(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF((TRANSPOSE(A:A)<=A:A)*(TRANSPOSE(C:C)=C:C),D:D,)
 ,,9^99))),"CLOSED"))},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col5=1"))
```

Essentially,

- First assigning a count to each row for any given order
- Transpose and combine statuses
- If there is a CLOSED status in there, don't use it
- Then filter with query language

Resulting in—

[image]

See solution [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxq3QcRBX6QpSyEe2IGgxq6CTk1zk3Of-YbO09U7N2A/edit#gid=764300252).

**Mod**

I added a clause to completely exclude the status NOTE from current records—

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:D,(COUNTIFS(B:B,B:B,A:A,">="&A:A)=1)*(D:D="CLOSED")+ 
 (ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ARRAYFORMULA(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY
 (IF((TRANSPOSE(A:A)<=A:A)*(TRANSPOSE(B:B)=B:B),D:D,),,9^99))),"CLOSED"))))    
 =TRUE,IF((ARRAYFORMULA(NOT(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(D:D)))="NOTE")))  
 =FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),FALSE)))},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col5=1"))
```

**Implementation**

This was sample tested against 2500 rows of data, and took over 80 seconds to execute. So although this answers the question, it isn't necessarily a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(SORT({VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 SORT({B2:B, TO_TEXT(A2:D)}, 2, 0), {2, 3, 4, 5}, 0); 
 FILTER(A2:D, D2:D="RETURN")},1,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! That's a great option.